# Exception in calling a function from another javascript file - Metro App

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-8.1

```
          args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(TodoList.init()));
```

The above statement throws me an exception that TodoList is undefined.Actually, TodoList.js is a Javascript file located in the js folder of the Metro App Blank Project along with default.js.I am calling the init() function of the TodoList js file.What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what you do wrong. But it works for me. I created js file with next content:

```
var TodoList = {
    init: function () {
        (new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("TodoList.init()", "Message")).showAsync().done();
    }
};
```

and I added link to this file in `default.html`:

```
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/TodoList.js"></script>
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
```

and I got my message. Please, recheck your code at least for reference to your js file.

Comment: Yeah, Windows 8 JavaScript apps work just like web pages, make sure you have a `<script>` tag in your html file!